# Unable to capture hostname on ping with gethostname

Tags: python-3.x, networking

I'm new to python and I'm trying to ping my office network and trying to get the hostnames for an inventory system I'm trying to build for work. When I run the script below, I get the IP Address and get either Online or Offline, but I don't get the correct hostname. I only get the hostname of the computer sending out the ping. I think I need to capture it with a string but not sure how to do that.  Ultimately this will be run in a GUI with the push of a button.

```
import ipaddress
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import socket

network = ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.1.0/24')
for i in network.hosts():
        i = str(i)
        h = socket.gethostname()
        toping = Popen(['ping', '-c', '5', '-w', '100', i], stdout=PIPE)
        output = toping.communicate()[0]
        hostalive = toping.returncode
        if hostalive == 0:
            print(i)
            print(h)
            print("Is Online")
        else:
            print(i)
            print("Is Offline")
```

Comment: Try adding the option `-a` with ping, and check if it helps.

Comment: Do you mean add it to the "toping" line? If so where?

Comment: I think you should try with this line `toping = Popen(['ping', '-a', '-c', '5', '-w', '100', i], stdout=PIPE)`. Check the -a option carefully.